# Linear Transformations

Tags: linear-algebra

> 1) Let $A$ be a $3 \times 4$ matrix with nullity($A$) $= 1$. Let $T$ be the linear map given by $T(x) = A^\top x$. 
>   Is $T$ one-to-one?

The dimensions of $A^\top$ would be $4 \times 3$, and since the cols of $A^\top$ are linearly independent, there exists a trivial solution; therefore $T$ is one-to-one.

Question: In class, we never did an example regarding the relationship between nullity and one-to-oneness, so I'm not quite if my answer to this question is correct. How do I answer this question using the nullity? What is the relationship between nullity of $A^\top$ and one-to-oneness?

> 2) For what values of $a$ is the matrix $A$ invertible?
>
> $$A = \begin{bmatrix}
>        a & a^2-8 & 1           \\[0.3em]
>        0 & a-3 & 0           \\[0.3em]
>        2 & a^2-64 & a-1           
>      \end{bmatrix}$$

So instead of using the method of row reduction with the identity matrix, I decided to use the determinant theorem: If $\det(A) \neq 0$, then $A$ is invertible. Taking the determinant, I found that $\det(A) = 6$. Would someone please double check this? I am studying for a test and the textbook does not provide answers for these questions.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For $1)$: We have: $\text{dim A} = \text{rank(A)} + \text{nullity(A)}\Rightarrow 4 = \text{rank(A)} + 1\Rightarrow \text{rank(A)} = 3\Rightarrow \text{rank($A^t$)} = 3$. Invoking the rank-nullity theorem again: $\text{dim($A^t$)} = \text{rank($A^t$)} + \text{nullity($A^t$)} \Rightarrow 3 = 3 + \text{nullity($A^t$)} \Rightarrow \text{nullity($A^t$)} = 0 \Rightarrow T$ is one-to-one.

For $2)$: Expanding the determinant along the second row: $|A| = (a-3)(a(a-1)-2)=(a-3)(a^2-a-2)=(a-3)(a-2)(a+1)$. Thus for $A$ to be invertible, $a \neq -1,2,3$.